# Problem with textfield in my first Flutter app build

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm learning flutter and I've developed my first todo app. The issue I'm experiencing is that the app works well on debug mode on my device and emulator but when I run flutter run build command and install the release apk the textfield where you enter the Todo item doest work and instead I get a grey box.
I'll append some images to clarify. I'm a noob so it's probable that I missed something. I just wanted to test my app as a release apk to see if it was fluent.

Thanks for your help!

this is the debug apk that vscode installs in my Motorola one

[image: this is the debug apk that vscode installs in my Motorola one]

[image: this is how that dialog looks like on the release apk]

this is how that dialog looks like on the release apk

I've uploaded the project for you to see but here is the Form code and the list

TodoItemForm.dart:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo/models/TodoItemModel.dart';

class TodoItemForm extends StatefulWidget {
  TodoItemForm({
    Key key,
    @required this.context,
    this.item,
    this.onSubmit,
    this.onClose,
  }) : super(key: key) {
    if (this.item == null)
      this.item = new TodoItemModel("", false, DateTime.now(), DateTime.now());
  }

  final BuildContext context;
  TodoItemModel item;
  final ValueChanged<TodoItemModel> onSubmit;
  final VoidCallback onClose;
  @override
  _TodoItemFormState createState() => _TodoItemFormState();
}

class _TodoItemFormState extends State<TodoItemForm> {
  TextEditingController _todoItemTextController = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.item != null) {
      _todoItemTextController.value = TextEditingValue(text: widget.item.text);
    } else {
      widget.item = new TodoItemModel(
          _todoItemTextController.text, false, DateTime.now(), DateTime.now());
    }
  }

  void onSubmit() {
    widget.item.text = _todoItemTextController.text;
    widget.onSubmit(widget.item);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 10, 0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.playlist_add,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "New To Do Item",
          ),
        ],
      ),
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
      content: Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          controller: _todoItemTextController,
          autofocus: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Task to do:",
            hintText: "Buy Groseries!",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: this.onSubmit,
          child: Text(
            "SAVE",
            style: new TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
          ),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: widget.onClose,
          child: Text(
            "CANCEL",
            style: new TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

TaskList.dart:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo/models/TodoItemModel.dart';
import 'package:todo/services/TodoServiceProvider.dart';
import 'package:todo/widgets/TodoItem.dart';
import 'package:todo/widgets/TodoItemForm.dart';

class TaskList extends StatefulWidget {
  TaskList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TaskListState createState() => _TaskListState();
}

class _TaskListState extends State<TaskList> {
  List<TodoItemModel> _items = [];
  final _todoItemTextController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.refreshTodos();
  }

  void refreshTodos() {
    TodoServiceProvider.getTodoItems().then((todoList) {
      setState(() {
        _items = todoList;
      });
    });
  }

  void _handleSubmit(TodoItemModel newItem) {
    TodoServiceProvider.createTodo(newItem).then((todoItem) {
      this.refreshTodos();
      this._handleClose();
    });
  }

  void _handleEdit(TodoItemModel item) {
    TodoServiceProvider.updateTodo(item).then((todoItem) {
      this.refreshTodos();
      this._handleClose();
    });
  }

  void _handleClose() {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    _todoItemTextController.clear();
  }

  Future<bool> _handleItemCompleted(TodoItemModel model, DismissDirection dir) {
    return TodoServiceProvider.deleteTodo(model.id).then((response) {
      if (response) {
        setState(() {
          _items.remove(model);
        });
        return Future.value(true);
      }
      return Future.value(false);
    }).catchError((error) => Future.value(false));
  }

  void _showTodoItemForm({TodoItemModel item: null}) {
    final alert = TodoItemForm(
      context: context,
      item: item,
      onSubmit: item == null ? this._handleSubmit : this._handleEdit,
      onClose: this._handleClose,
    );

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Todo"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: _showTodoItemForm,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ReorderableListView(
                onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                  this.setState(() {
                    final aux = _items[oldIndex];
                    if (oldIndex > newIndex) {
                      _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
                      _items.insert(newIndex, aux);
                    } else {
                      _items.insert(newIndex, aux);
                      _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
                    }
                  });
                },
                children: [
                  for (final _item in _items)
                    FlatButton(
                      key: ValueKey(_item),
                      child: TodoItem(
                        model: _item,
                        onItemCompleted: this._handleItemCompleted,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        this._showTodoItemForm(item: _item);
                      },
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

TodoItemModel.dart:

```
import 'package:todo/widgets/TodoItem.dart';

class TodoItemModel {
  int _id;
  String _text;
  bool _finished;
  DateTime _creationDate;
  DateTime _dueDate;

  TodoItemModel(this._text, this._finished, this._creationDate, this._dueDate);

  int get id => _id;
  String get text => _text;
  DateTime get creationDate => _creationDate;

  void set text(String value) {
    _text = value;
  }

  void set id(int value) => _id = value;

      
  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["text"] = _text;
    map["creation_date"] = _creationDate.toIso8601String();
    if (_id != null) map["id"] = _id;

    return map;
  }

  TodoItemModel.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this._id = json["id"];
    this._text = json["text"];
    this._creationDate = DateTime.parse(json["creation_date"]);
  }
}
```

Full project url:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tNue3EfdwV_7M7zHt_A7A4RsNIdppHqj?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share you code so i can track you issue.Flutter display Grey screen in release mode when error come.

Comment: @NikhilVadoliya Sorry for the delay, thanks for your answer, I hope you can still help me... I've updated my question with the code and a link to the full project. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add TodoItemModel file or share github/git link

Comment: I can't unzip it

Comment: @NikhilVadoliya Thanks for the help!, I've added the model code to the question and updated the link with the folder instead of the compressed file... I dont have this project on github so it was quicker this way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the **Expanded Widget** in AlertDialog.

TodoItemForm.dart:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo/models/TodoItemModel.dart';

class TodoItemForm extends StatefulWidget {
  TodoItemForm({
    Key key,
    @required this.context,
    this.item,
    this.onSubmit,
    this.onClose,
  }) : super(key: key) {
    if (this.item == null)
      this.item = new TodoItemModel("", false, DateTime.now(), DateTime.now());
  }

  final BuildContext context;
  TodoItemModel item;
  final ValueChanged<TodoItemModel> onSubmit;
  final VoidCallback onClose;
  @override
  _TodoItemFormState createState() => _TodoItemFormState();
}

class _TodoItemFormState extends State<TodoItemForm> {
  TextEditingController _todoItemTextController = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.item != null) {
      _todoItemTextController.value = TextEditingValue(text: widget.item.text);
    } else {
      widget.item = new TodoItemModel(
          _todoItemTextController.text, false, DateTime.now(), DateTime.now());
    }
  }

  void onSubmit() {
    widget.item.text = _todoItemTextController.text;
    widget.onSubmit(widget.item);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 10, 0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.playlist_add,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "New To Do Item",
          ),
        ],
      ),
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
      content: Container( //Change this line
        child: TextField(
          controller: _todoItemTextController,
          autofocus: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Task to do:",
            hintText: "Buy Groseries!",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: this.onSubmit,
          child: Text(
            "SAVE",
            style: new TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
          ),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: widget.onClose,
          child: Text(
            "CANCEL",
            style: new TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll check this. The thing that seems strange to me is that the development apk works fine but the build apk is the one that breaks. I'll test this later today. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue with a dialog in release build, but for me it was a "Spacer()" within the dialog which causes this behavior.